# Where is the look of the Search button in Bootsrap5 defined?

Tags: 9, bootstrap-theme

I have a Drupal 9.5.1 website with [**Bootstrap5**](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap5) 2.0.6 as its base theme. The theme by default places a search form by means of a block named "Search" in the "Additional navigation region".

This block "Search" is provided by core, but how its looks seems to be determined by the theme. If I change the theme to **Bartik**, the same block by default appears in the "Sidebar first" region, but the button to press to search is an icon (I believe it is `fa-search` from FontAwesome), not the text "Search".

I have enabled Twig debugging, and found that in **Bootstrap5** the search form is themed by:

```
themes/contrib/bootstrap5/templates/form/input.html.twig
```

In **Bartik**, the search form is themed by:

```
core/modules/system/templates/input.html.twig
```

In my subtheme, I want to do replace the text "Search" on the button with a an icon, just like you get by default if you set **Bartik** as the default.

But I am unable to locate *where* the look of of the Search button is defined and how to change it from text to the `fa-search` icon that is used by **Bartik**.

So far I've looked for it in the templates that comes with **Bootstrap5** and from core (used by **Bartik**), including the `input.html.twig` that comes with both. There are subtle differences, but I am not able to pinpoint where the icon used by default by **Bartik** comes from.

I have tried to swap the one from core into my **Bootstrap5** subtheme. This just removes the background colour on the button, but has no other effect.

Comment: You’ll need to provide some more info to get a definitive answer - how is the search from provided to the site? Is it core search or search API? Is it a block? Is it an exposed filter from a View? There’s probably not a special template that already exists for the search form (it’s just a form), so you’ll need to work out how it came into existence to find out how to alter it. To clarify, Bootstrap is just a theme, it wouldn’t provide that form and its functionality, that comes from a module

Comment: @Clive It is a block named "Search" that is provided by core, and that is placed in a specific region by the theme. I *believe* its look & feel is determined by the theme, because if you set the **Bartik** theme as default, it still on the page, but with a different look. I have added this information to the question.

Comment: @FreeRadical Have you enabled Twig debugging to determine which theme file renders it?

Comment: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.1.x/core/modules/search/src/Form/SearchBlockForm.php

Comment: In the linked theme there are preprocess hooks and templates for single form elements. That's all. ‍♂️

Comment: @cilefen I have now enabled twig debugging and found and examined the theme file rendering the Search field, but I am not wiser.

Answer (score 0):

The twig template is, **probably**:

```
core/modules/system/templates/input.html.twig
```

So, I think there are not many options other than something like copy core/modules/system/templates/input.html.twig to your subtheme and edit it to something like:

```
{% if (attributes.id == 'the-id-of-the-submit') %}
  {%
    set classes = [
      'some-class',
      'some-other-class',
    ]
  %}
  <button{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}></button>
{% else %}
  <input{{ attributes }} />{{ children }}
{% endif %}
```